# What does this for in loop mean and why it just prints out 0 and 1?

Tags: javascript

It is so funny that the following for in loop prints out 0 and 1. 
Anybody helps to explain: 1 what does it mean for variable in a lambda function? 2. why prints out 0 and 1? (I changed the ['a', 'b'] to [1,2], it still prints 0 and 1.

```
for (var f in d = function(){}, ['a', 'b']){console.log(f)}
```

prints out

```
0  
1
```

Comment: [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loops always iterate an object's enumerable keys/properties. Even for `Array`s, `f` is being assigned the indices, [possibly among other keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea).

Comment: It's not a syntax error, but in the above `d` has no purpose

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I don't think that's accurate.  I believe the for..in is iterating over the last argument, in this case the array.  `d` will still be a function at the end of the loop and has no purpose in the above.  You could assign or use any number of variables `var b=[];  for( var p in a='',b,c=function(){},… ){ … }`

Comment: OK.  For the line as `for (var f in d = function(){}){console.log(f)}`, function object seems to have no enumerable keys/properties, and nothing is printed out. Right? However, why doesn't engine report any error or warning such as this useless code?

Comment: @vol7ron Not a homework. I am working on a custom JavaScript translator.

Comment: @user3470598 A `Function` is still an `Object` in JavaScript and at least *could* have enumerable properties to iterate over. `(function(){} instanceof Object) // true`.

Comment: "why doesn't engine report any error or warning such as this useless code" --- because it's not an error, it's a valid JS code.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski "The function(){} is discarded by the comma operator, returning ['a', 'b'] to be assigned (=) to d" --- this is wrong.

Comment: @user3470598 There is no such thing as a useless code error in JavaScript.  JavaScript is interpreted.

Comment: @PHPglue Unfortunately, I can not change customers code. and the translator has to deal with it.

Comment: @zerkms exactly what i meant in my comment after his

Comment: Awesome! Didn't know it is such a great community!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The

```
for (var f in d = function(){}, ['a', 'b']) ...
```

can be explained if you wrap the `in` clause into the parentheses:

```
for (var f in (d = function(){}, ['a', 'b']) )
```

where `(d = function(){}, ['a', 'b'])` is an expression enclosed in parentheses. The expression consists of 2 another expressions and a `,` operator.

[`,` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) in turn evaluates both operands and returns the latter.

So in your case the `d = function(){}` assigns the anonymous function to a variable `d` and then the array with 2 elements is returned.

To summarize: the `d = function(){}` expression is not ignored and you can use `d` in the statements after this loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is a weird behavior, but to elaborate this, the javascript for...in loop through values in an array, but this array is the last parameter.

```
for (var f in d =null, ['a', 'b']){console.log(f)} //prints 0,1

for (var f in null, ['a', 'b'],['a', 'b','c'],['a', 'b','c','d']){console.log(f)}//prints 0,1,2,3
```

so basically it does not matter what d is, or other parameters, the last parameter, in this example ['a', 'b','c','d'], is the array that this for loop loop through

also note

```
for (var f in d =function(){}, ['a', 'b']){console.log(d[f])} //prints undefined
```

print undefined. the ['a','b'] is not assigned to d

Answer (score 0):

You are logging the key of the array, so since it has 2 entries, it prints out 0 and 1. Maybe this will help you understand

```
for(var key in array){
  console.log(key, array[key]);
}
```

so the key (or index) would be a number representing where in the array your data is. You can then get your value by going `array[key]`

Comment: Tested. You are right. HOWEVER, what is the anonymous function `function(){}` doing here? Is it something to ignore completely?